# Why is jQuery used to fetch CSS assets?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-devtools

Screenshot from Chrome Dev Tools:
[image: Screenshot from Chrome Dev Tools]

I was wondering, as the question says: why are my CSS assets fetched by jQuery?

The CSS sheet is included as you normally would; a `<link rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>` tag. jQuery and jQueryUI are then included as the last thing in the body.

When I go to the according line (6128), it shows me the function `curCSS`.. I can't really find anything about it, only that it's being used by jQueryUI and that it's been depricated.

```
jQuery         v1.11.1
Google Chrome  v39.0.2171.65 (64-bit)
```

---

### EDIT1:

Those assets are *not* used by jQueryUI. They are just some background images and fonts for my content.

---

### EDIT2:

I have commented jQueryUI out, reloaded the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and now they're still loaded by, but now with something on line 3580.

`**jQuery.js snippet removed for brevity**`

When I comment out jQuery as well they are loaded as normal.

---

### EDIT3:

**To clarify why I loaded only jQuery + UI and no other scripts:**
I had included jQuery + UI in my base template, and I loaded another page that didn't use jQuery at all. I went to debug that page and noticed jQuery was doing strange things :P

This is the least markup possible:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pagetitle</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="font-family: ArialNarrowBold">CONTENT</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the Chrome dev-tools look like this:

[image: Chrome devtools 2]

The `ArialNarrowBold` font is in `fonts.css`. As you can see I have no further scripting on the page, besides including jQuery and jQuery-UI. Even if I take out the `jquery-ui.min.css` this keeps the same.

Even when I load the font in a `style` block, jQuery still wants to load it himself..

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ArialNarrowBold';
        src: url('fonts/ArialNarrowBold.eot');
        src: url('fonts/ArialNarrowBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fonts/ArialNarrowBold.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fonts/ArialNarrowBold.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: If it's used by jQueryUI, doesn't that just mean it's importing it into the DOM using jQuery, so it can be properly used in the UI?

Comment: That is the thing. Those assets aren't jQueryUI's assets. They're completely not related to jQuery at all.

Comment: Weird... Have you tried removing it from the jQuery file, for testing purpose? It states `$.curCSS: This method was simply an alias for jQuery.css() from jQuery 1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was “more efficient.” Now it’s “more gone.”` on the jQuery website, so it looks like it shouldn't even be there. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery version 1.11.1

Comment: are you sure that they are the css assets? normally if you make a ajax request with jquery, or if you load any dom elemenet (ex. img) with jquery, you will get that kind of report in the console.

Comment: Are there any other scripts included in addition to jQuery on page? Or just jQuery + jQueryUI?

Comment: @Zudwa - just jQuery + jQueryUI, not even inline JS or my own JS files

Comment: Could you provide a page markup? Probably it can help to figure out the truth.

Comment: Yes, please provide a page markup... at least of your entire `<HEAD>` section and the "bottom" of the page where you load **jquery** and **jqueryui.js**

Comment: I guess it's nature of jquery, it always tries to fallback if something goes wrong, as it supports old IE versions. So in source of jquery you will find `var rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:]+)[^>]*)\/>/gi;`, then it's used somewhere below with `value = value.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" );`, im not sure but guess jquery tries to inspect DOM and replaces some unclosing tags, and then, tags compiled by browser. But it's only a suggesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a regression in Chrome Devtools. I just double checked using Chrome Canary and Chromium, and I'm unable to replicate this situation on either one of the browsers. You should definitely report this issue: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Before you submit the bug report, please check if you are on the latest version of Chrome, if not see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same when I use jquery to add some image src attribute.
If you notice the column that writes that information is "**Initiator**":

[image: Chrome console network]

It seems that Chrome traces in that column the script that causes the start of the request.
Maybe you are loading some html with jquery, that has css inside, or any asset that is not linkend with css.

Example:

```
$(img).attr('src', 'image.png');

//OR
$(div).load('/load/index.html');
```

will cause that kind of information on chrome console.

Comment: Seems reasonable. If only I used some of that code.. The CSS in question has nothing to do with jQuery. Heck I don't even have *any* JS code loaded...

Comment: What do you mean you don't have any JS loaded? You mean the only `<script src=..></script>` that you have is one for **jquery.js** and one for **jqueryui.js**?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno - correct, I included jQuery + UI in my base template, then went to debug a page using that template but without any other scripting.

Comment: maybe it is a Chrome bug

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the website on Firefox, and check it there.
If that countinue saying: "jQuery", that will be the end of the world.
But, if says "nothing", could be an issue on Chrome. Report it!

Comment: I can't seem to find anything of an `initiator` like in Chrome... Not on Firebug nor in Firefox' own inspector

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery on the page, right?  Otherwise why would you be loading it?

Please include as much markup as possible, especially any use of jQuery (inline, in script tags, etc...)

- Are you making AJAX calls... you'll often see this sort of thing as a response.
- What about AJAX JSONP?
- Are you using Ruby?

  - If so... are you using **`.js.erb` files**?   -- I've seen this happen when `.js.erb` files are returned from the server from an AJAX call on the page and the returning JavaScript is injected directly into the page and run.

Comment: Also, I don't use any of the things listed. I use Python. But this page is just a html file loaded from static directory.